# ostream cout and char *

Tags: c++, char, ostream

I have an array of chars like this one:

```
char arr[3]="hi";
cout << arr;// this will print out hi
```

So is the operator<< has an overloaded version that takes an ostream object and char *. so `cout<<arr;` first arr will decays to a chat * . and then operator<<() will print out what the char pointer is pointing to until it find a null-character ?

**The same question for**  `cin>>arr;` how does it work with operator>> that takes an array as the second operand.

Comment: Yes, there are lots of overloaded versions. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/operator<</ Or was that not the question?

Comment: also http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/operator%3E%3E/

Comment: Also don't use cplusplus.com, but cppreference.com.

Comment: @MrLister, simply: cplusplus.com is *really* outdated and inaccurate, while cppreference.com covers everything (maybe without examples everywhere, but they will come) that is mentioned in latest C++ standard.

Comment: Hm, I find cplusplus to be much more readable. Too bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ostream` and `istream` do have `operator<<` and `operator>>` overloaded to take a `char*`, and arrays decay into pointers to the first element.  So, yes it does what you say it does.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly in the same way as `cout` works.

The array `arr` decays into pointer type, and there exists an overloaded version of `istream` as well which takes `char*` as argument. So `arr` gets passed to the `operator>>` as `char*` after decaying.

Answer (score 0):

Please see here for details on `cout`: [Standard output stream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cout/). Whilst in this page, please click and see the link that says "[ostream::operator<<](http://www.cplusplus.com/ostream%3a%3aoperator%3C%3C)"
Likewise see here for details on `cin`: [Standard input stream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cin/). Whilst here, please click and see the link that says "[operator (>>)](http://www.cplusplus.com/istream%3a%3aoperator%3E%3E)"